# Calibrating the magnetic field sensor

Tags: java, android, sensors, magnetometer

How do I calibrate the magnetic field sensor?

I know it is done by software.
Can I get the Java API code?

Comment: Why did you tag this with MATLAB yet you are clearly trying to figure this out for Java / Android?  I've removed the MATLAB tag because it's just nonsense.

Comment: Sorry, I need a MATLAB Code. I´ve forgotten to mention this.

Comment: Your post says you need to know how to do this on Java / Android yet your comment says you want to do it in MATLAB... so which one is it?